# Google map doesn't get displayed.

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

here is the link for fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5GqB6/

```
var directionsDisplay;  
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();  
var map;  
var geocoder, location1, location2;  

........
```

Comment: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/

Comment: please include all the relevant code in the question, not just a link to a fiddle with random code so you can submit the question.  The code posted in the question certainly won't display a map.

Comment: YOu should have posted your requirement clearly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am expecting your requirement is to draw a route between two cities displaying its information in the side corner.**

Please check this code:

[Working Example of Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel)

Comment: Thank you very much Shirish... this helps. Do you also know how to add code in this to compute distance between the two points and display it? That would be of great help to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: I think i got the diatance calculation by adding the code below....      function computeTotalDistance(result) {
      var total = 0;
      var myroute = result.routes[0];
      for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
      }
      total = (total / 1000);
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total + " km";
      }

Comment: Yes you have written the perfect code for implementing distance calculation between route for your functionality. If you think my answer has helped you. Do accept it.:-)